# Как правильно выставить блоки относительно контейнера?

Tags: html, css

Помогите пожалуйста. Разметил такую шапку, и вот header__content его текст должен быть слева по центру. В общем, я прокомментировал разметку. Не могу понять, что не так делаю.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
/*   Тут картинка */
  background-color: red;
}

.header__wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.header__top {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.header__row {
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

.header__content {
  display: flex;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="header__wrap">
    <div class="header__top">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="" class="logo">Лого</a>
        <nav class="header__menu">...</nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header__row">
      <div class="header__content content-header">
        <div class="container">
<!--           должен быть слева по центру -->
          <div class="content-header__text"> 
            <h1>text</h1>
          </div>
<!--           должен быть справа внизу относительно контейнера -->
          <div class="content-header__actions">
            <a href="" class="btn">Кнопка</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: CodePen: https://codepen.io/jdkf7d8fdoi/pen/rNQMVLq

Comment: @KILLER `слева по центру` -- так слева или по центру? Или Вы имеете ввиду слева и вертикально по центру?

Comment: И какое же отчие? Слева по центру! Я не писал по центру

Comment: @KILLER отличие в том что это не слишком конкретизировано. Для того чтобы Ваш текст не был по центру, а находился слева, то нужно дать ширину на контейнер `width: 100%`. Что касается вертикального выравнивания, то скорее всего Вам придется повесить кнопку на абсолют, потому что четко по центру текст выровнять не выйдет, так как будет учитывать Вашу кнопку, что влияет на высоту. К тому же высота контейнера у Вас формируется высотой содержимого, потому не совсем понятно каким образом Вы это хотите вертикально центрировать и относительно чего.